# Regex to accept multiple date formats

Tags: regex

So here's what I need to identify
Dates with Formatted as:
1/2/2022
01/02/2022
01/2/2022
1/02/20202

So basically, date formats like:
mm/dd/yyyy
m/d/yyyy
mm/d/yyyy
m/dd/yyyy
m/d/yyyy

As much as I hate it, the files that I get are always a mix of these date formats.

I've tried this regex format

```
(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/?|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:(?:0?2)(\/?|-|\.)(?:29)\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/?|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

But It can't seem to get some dates.

Comment: i would split by '/ ', much simpler

Comment: First of all: by rules of [tag:regex] tag, you have to also tag with the engine or programming language you use. Secondly, "can't get some dates" is vague, can't you give examples? Finally — you can test whether a string is in a date format very simply using regex; but testing whether it represents a valid date is not something that should be attempted with regexp, because insanity lies that way. Let alone leap years, regex can't handle the case of e.g. 02/30/1712, which is the only February 30 that ever existed, and only in Sweden.

Comment: Can you not use a library to parse dates from strings?  Using a regex is generally going to be much trickier to work out if a date is valid.  You don't want to be e.g. working out if it is a leap year in a regex, ideally.

Comment: Using edge-case examples that have a day that can also be a month are of little use. Please change your example to have a day that is 13 or more. Also, which date are in the "can't seem to get some dates" category?

Answer (score 0):

In a naïve simple way, this regex will match strings with those date stamps

```
^(?:[0-3]?\d[\/]){2}\d{4}$
```

Basically 2 groups of 1 to 2 digits with a slash, followed by 4 digits.
And the first 2 numbers will range from 0 to 39.
But this would also allow strings like '0/32/0000'

A more specific regex to limit those ranges between 1 and 31 :

```
^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/]){2}[0-9]{4}$
```

But this will still allow datestamps like `31/31/2000`

If a negative lookahead is added those can be avoided.

```
^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])|(?:1[3-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])(?![\/](?:1[3-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])))[\/](?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/][0-9]{4}$
```

This won't match something like '15/15/2000'.
But it won't care about how many days a month has.

Test on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/dXrVPI/1)